# Firebase-Dart exception in set

Tags: dart, firebase

I'm trying the firebase-dart package,
using `set` save the right value in the database but launch the exception:

```dart
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'call'

NoSuchMethodError: incorrect number of arguments passed to method named 'call'
Receiver: Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic
Tried calling: call(null, "")
Found: call(err)
```

Here it is the source code:

```dart
library reverser;

import 'dart:html';
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' show Firebase;

const firebaseUrl = 'https://laquyfire.firebaseio.com/';

// Example of hooking into the DOM and responding to changes from input fields.
initReverser() {
  var output = querySelector('#out');
  var input = querySelector('#name');
  input.onKeyUp.listen((_) {
    output.text = input.value.split('').reversed.join();
    var fb = new Firebase('${firebaseUrl}');
    var value = {'reversed': output.text};

      fb.set(value).then((result) => print(result.snapshot));    
  });
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you do a `fb.child('/some-child').set(value)`? By the way, you can just do `new Firebase(firebaseUrl)`.

Comment: Same error with child(...).set

Answer (score 1):

The source code appears to be based on the WebStorm `Web Applicaion` sample project. I created a new project based on that sample project and besides adding the posted source code to `lib/reverser.dart`, did only three additional things to make it work:

- Added this line inside the `<head>` tag in `index.html`:

  `<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.2/firebase.js"></script>`
- Added this line to the `dependencies:` section in the `pubspec.yaml` file:

  `firebase: ">=0.5.1 <0.6.0"`
- Called `pub get` from the project directory

After that, the project worked and the reversed text was added to the Firebase database. Were the same changes made to your project? Perhaps a different version of the Firebase pub package was used, or perhaps an incompatible JavaScript file was referenced in the `<script>` tag? I am using Dart SDK 1.10.0_r45396.

There is an unrelated issue with the source code in the post: Upon success, the value of the future returned from `Firebase.set()` will be null, so `print(result.snapshot)` will cause an exception.